# How to gett the Outlook PWA launchers back on Plasma

Tags: kde, launcher, plasma, webapps, office365

On my Ubuntu 22 system I use the KDE/Plasma desktop. I had launchers for the Outlook and Teams progressive web apps (PWA) in my menu, until I used the `rm -rf` command a bit too enthusiastically on my .local share directory, which emptied the panel completely...

Now I can open Office 365 (for work) as a PWA and put a launcher on the panel, and also for OneDrive. But when I open Outlook or Teams as a PWA, they don't show up in the applications list so I cannot add them as a launcher?

My guess is that these two fail to appear because I had their launchers before and I need to delete more files of my previous menu setting before I can add them again. Would anyone know if this is correct and if yes, what those files are?

Many thanks.